# Shift vs Shuffle usage for marking a changement in position

Tags: word-usage

I'm not a native English speaker, and I have a big doubt with the usage in everyday language when I'm changing something's position.

I was used to know that "shuffle" means put in a randorm order, while "shift" was used to signify a known change, for example:
"I'm shuffling the deck of card"
"I'll shift Alexandre's seat from table 31 to table 7"

However, I met someone from Australia which said that "shift" was almost never used in these cases in English language. Is that a specificity of this country, or a global "common rule"?

Comment: In the U.S. and Canada, *move* would be used in preference to *shift*.  But *shift* is fine.

Comment: Can confirm that _shift_ is almost never used in Australia. _Move_ is also the preferred term here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think the rule (if there is one) is as clear as you've been taught. Shuffling a deck of cards should be random. A cabinet reshuffle, where government ministers change jobs, should not.